# View collection in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have to make sure to display points and multilinestrings in a single geometry.

I tried with the geometry collection and it displays the dot and the line correctly.

The problem is that QGIS doesn't display the geometry.

Is it possible to somehow standardize everything?.

I will also have to create a layer that includes points, polygons, lines and I would need them in a single geometry.

Comment: You each layer is a single geometry, you cannot have one layer with multiple geometries in QGIS as I know of.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

A geometry can be created in each layer, you need to create three layers that include point, line, polygon, using existing tools or Python programming, create the connection you want between them.